# PDO - CountRow - Error:: non-object

Tags: php, pdo

I have a little problem.

```
$query = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? OR mail = ?");
$query = $query->execute(array($username, $mail));
echo $query;
$rows = $query->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
$numrows = count($rows);
```

I get this: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchALL() on a non-object!
Any help please.

EDIT1:

This is working now, but SQL is not execute.

```
$query = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? OR mail = ?");
$result = $query->execute(array($username, $mail));
$count = $query->rowCount();
if ($count == 0) {
//
$query = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username,password,mail) VALUES (?,?,?)");
$query = $query->execute(array($username, $password, $mail));
//somewhere is mistake :(
```

EDIT2:

Everything is ok...
My structure in db was username, password and email not mail :)

Comment: try $count = $query->rowCount();

Comment: Please mark an answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

You are renaming $query. 
Change $query = $query->execute(... to $execute = $query->execute(...

Then $rows = $query->fetchAll(...

Comment: woudln't it be "$execute->fetchAll(" if it was changed that way?

Answer (score 0):

try the following code

```
$query = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? OR mail = ?");
         $query->execute(array($username, $mail));

         $count = $query->rowCount();
         $rows = $query->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
```

Comment: If it's working what makes you think the SQL is wrong? What are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

You are reassigning the $query variable 
Try

```
    $query = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? OR email = ?");
    $result = $query->execute(array($username, $mail));
    $rows = $result->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
    $numrows = count($rows);
```

For other question try

```
   $query = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? OR mail = ?");
   $result = $query->execute(array($username, $mail));
   $count = $query->rowCount();
   if ($count == 0) {

    $query = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username,password,email) VALUES             (:username, :password, :mail)";)
    $query->execute(array(':username'=> $username,
                             ':password'=> $password,
                              ':email'= $mail));

 }
```